# Reducing time taken to predict probabilities

Tags: python, keras, prediction

I am using Keras with Tensorflow backend. Once I have the model I am using model.predict_proba to predict probabilities. The time taken by this predict function seems to be independent of the size of the array, or rather less dependent on the size of the array that it is predicting.

What can I do to reduce this time taken?

First I run the loop 100 times and time the predictions as below

```
fname_model = folder+"/my_modelbuy_rocbased.h5"
best_model = load_model(fname_model)
best_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', 
metrics=['acc'])
X_test_orig = pd.read_csv(folder+"/ret_out_20170402.csv",sep=",")
x_test = X_test_orig.as_matrix()
y1=np.array([x_test[1]])
print y1.shape 
t1=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
for i in range(0,100,1):
prob1= best_model.predict_proba(y1)
t2=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")   
print "time taken ", t1,t2
```

**********************************************After Running***********************

time taken  11:50:53.909226 11:50:54.372596

---

So for 100 predictions, the time taken was 11:50:54.372596 minus 11:50:53.909226 which is about 463 milliseconds, which would imply 4.63 milliseconds per prediction

However if i run the loop for just one prediction as shown below ,

```
fname_model = folder+"/my_modelbuy_rocbased.h5"
best_model = load_model(fname_model)
best_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', 
metrics=['acc'])
X_test_orig = pd.read_csv(folder+"/ret_out_20170402.csv",sep=",")
x_test = X_test_orig.as_matrix()
y1=np.array([x_test[1]])
print y1.shape 
t1=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
for i in range(0,1,1):
prob1= best_model.predict_proba(y1)
t2=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")   
print "time taken ", t1,t2
```

**********************************************After Running***********************

time taken  11:54:40.683225 11:54:41.144969

---

So for 1 prediction, the time taken is 11:54:40.683225 minus 11:54:41.144969 which is also about 440 milliseconds.

There seems to be a fixed amount of time the model will take regardless of the number of calls. How can I reduce this?

Comment: I have found that the first prediction always takes significantly longer on my ANN's with the others being almost instant. Try doing a single prediction before you take both times.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected because you are predicting individual inputs and the computation graph (model) is the same, so it will take the same time for predicting. It's like you are expecting a different runtime for the same computation which is not going to happen.

Now there is a way to speed up: instead of predicting single elements, convert them into an ndarray (samples, features) and just call `model.predict` which will process in *batches* and run the computation in parallel depending on your backend setup.

Another point is you don't need to *compile* to predict. Compilation adds the loss and optimiser operations to the graph which you do not need if you are just predicting. This will reduce the time for the model to be load in memory etc.

Comment: In reality, my y1 will always be of shape(1,31). That is I will always only have one sample to predict. Each time it will take me about 400 milliseconds. However, there is some setup that is happening at the backend which may not be required which is why when I for loop through the prediction the time took remains the same. Is there a way by which I can get rid of this "additional setup ". Can I keep the graph loaded in the memory so that predictions happen faster?